# while using cookies in Xunit Selenium C# Got System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object Error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, selenium-chromedriver, nullreferenceexception

```
    [Theory]
    [InlineData(BrowserType.Chrome)]
    [InlineData(BrowserType.Firefox)]
    public void GetCookies(BrowserType browserType)
    {
        using (var driver = WebDriverInfra.Create_Browser(browserType))
        {
            driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
           
            TestOutputHelper.WriteLine("Login is started.");

            Wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(LoginUrl);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("username")).SendKeys(Username);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("password")).SendKeys(Password);
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("submit")).Click();
            string welcomeSign = Wait.Until<string>(driver => driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/h2")).Text);
            welcomeSign.Should().NotBeNull();
            welcomeSign.Should().Contain("Welcome");

            var userFirstNameCookie = Driver.Manage().Cookies.GetCookieNamed("userFirstName")

           
            userFirstNameCookie.Value.Should().Be(FirstName);
           

            TestOutputHelper.WriteLine("login is completed.");
```

webDriverInfra.CS
public static IWebDriver Create_Browser(BrowserType browserType)
{
switch (browserType)
{
case BrowserType.Chrome:
return new ChromeDriver();
case BrowserType.Firefox:
return new FirefoxDriver();
default:
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(browserType), browserType, null);
}
}

Browsertype.CS
public enum BrowserType
{
NotSet,
Chrome,
Firefox,
}

Can anyone help me on this to get rid of the null reference exception. This is my whole code. My test is passing till login when it hits the cookie line the null exception appears.

Comment: Can you check whether you are using same object throughout program?

Comment: Null point happens because of that